# .eds to .dbc for simulink implementation

Tags: embedded, simulink, can-bus, canopen

I'm setting up some CAN blocks in simulink that needs .dbc files but the hardware manufacturer only provided .eds files. What tool should I use to convert the format for simulink implementation

Comment: I believe .dbc is for J1939 or such? .eds is the standard for CANopen.

Comment: DBC is/was the quasi standard format for all CAN not just J1939. It was created by Vector, though they never really provided much documentation for its format. But it's more and more replaced by ARXML due to AUTOSAR. ARXML is a standard and documented and can express much more, then DBC can.